How to manage windows firewall with local admin permission from a domain member machine by overriding group policy limits?
I have here a Win10 workstation machine where I have local admin right. However, I can not create firewall exceptions, because it is not allowed by the local policy. I have permission to alter the windows firewall, but I have no way to access anyone with the technological rights for that.
I think, as local admin, actually I could to that, only the ordinary firewall configurator does not allow it (because it consider the group policy).
Can I somehow allow it? It is not a problem if it is not an ordinary thing, like some command line magic, tool installation or so.

If you have permission to alter Windows Firewall, do you also have permission to run GPO editor, and change those policies?

@DrMoishePippik Probably not, but I can try it. It says that the group policy forbids it for me. It is a workplace laptop, not very rational rules. I am not allowed to just crack it but I can do any "supported" ways what a local admin can do, installing for example software and similars. I check that gpo editor and report soon.

@DrMoishePippik I have organizational and legal permission to alter it, but I have no permission in my win10 desktop settings.
